# Slim3 DI container access diferrence

Tags: php, dependency-injection, slim

```
$app->get('......',....)
$container=$this->getContainer();
```

Is there any difference between the following?  Pimple docs uses the former while slim examples the latter. Is any of the two considered more formal in PSR terms?

```
    $server=$container['App\Model\Server'];

    $server=$container->get('App\Model\Server');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slims Container implements the [Interop/ContainerInterface](https://github.com/container-interop/container-interop), whereas Pimple does not.
The Interop/ContainerInterface requires the container to have two methods: `get()`and `has()`. `get()` throws an exception (`NotFoundException`) when an entry is not found. With plain Pimple you only get a notice.